# Validate directive elements from a form on the main page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is about handling client side validations for a large Angular app. I have a big SPA app with different components which includes reusable components like zip control. Now I can integrate these components in my page form but how can I trigger the validations for elements residing within the components. For e.g. my zip component has city input box, state select box and zip input box, now how can I trigger validations for these components from form submit?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following solution for my application for now. I am able to validate the required fields with this solution.

I created two input field one from the directive and other within the form. I am able to show error messages for both the fields. Similarly this can be done for some other form of validations.

Here is my plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/laW9jYoNCszHlPeIl3Vs?p=preview

script.js

```js
var app = angular.module('validationModule', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);
app.directive('testDirective', testDirective);

function testDirective(){
  var testDirective = {
    template: 'First Name: <input type="text" name="fName" required ng-model="user.firstName">'
  };

  return testDirective;
}

mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mainCtrl($scope){
  $scope.submitForm = function(user){
    alert(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);
  }
}
```

Index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="validationModule">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-animate.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-sanitize.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.1.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid? submitForm(user) : ''" novalidate>
    <h1>Input User Name</h1><br/>
    <test-directive></test-directive><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName" required ng-model="user.lastName">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="myForm.$submitted">
      <div ng-show="myForm.fName.$error.required">
        First Name is required
      </div>
      <div ng-show="myForm.lName.$error.required">
        Last Name is required
      </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/><br/>
    <h1>Is form valid? {{myForm.$valid}}</h1>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```